# Download pdf file from database Magento 2 code

Tags: magento2, php, pdf, download

I have some `pdf` file that is saved in the table named `pdf_download`
the database name is `loc_pos`.

Need to download that file when I click.

```
<a href="http://domain.com/index.php?route=information/start_downloads&amp;name=<?php echo $category['name']; ?>&amp;download=drivers_manuals&amp;file=<?php echo $category['file']; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
```

Output is:

```
http://domain.com/index.php?route=information/start_downloads&name=SENSORMATIC AMS 1140 SECURITY DETECTION&download=drivers_manuals&file=20140715164946.pdf
```

This script is not working.

I think the route is not working properly.

Can someone help me to get the correct code?

Comment: You donot follow magento routing logic.

Comment: I know it's not magento routing logic.Plz help me with that.. Hope you can give me the correct code..

Answer (score 0):

```
$block->getUrl('information/start_downloads', ['name' => $category['name'], 'download' => 'drivers_manuals', 'file' => $category['file']]);
```

This will create url with params. Of course, you need Magento Controller that returns file.